# inputtext returns null after update the disabled/readonly option true to false

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a switch (boolean).And when switch is true,inputtext disabled option is true.When switch is false,inputtext disabled option is false and so I can input data.But this data returns null.

```
    <h:form id="form">
                <p:inputSwitch value="#{switchMB.isTrue}" onLabel="True"
                    offLabel="False">
                    <p:ajax update="inputText" />
                </p:inputSwitch>

                <p:inputText id="inputText" value="#{switchMB.inputTextValue}"
                    disabled="#{switchMB.isTrue}"  />

                <p:commandButton action="#{switchMB.addValue}" 
                    update=":form" value="Add"></p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

when I input the data in inputText,this data always returns null.How can I solve this problem? How to update disabled option in inputText and input the data correctly?thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of safeguard against tampered/hacked requests, the `disabled` attribute is *also* evaluated during apply request values phase of the form submit. So basically you need to make sure that `#{switchMB.isTrue}` evaluates exactly the same as it did during rendering the form. The easist way is to put the `#{switchMB}` managed bean in the view scope instead of in the request scope.

```
@Named // Or @ManagedBean
@ViewScoped // Watch out that you import from the right package!
public class SwitchMB {}
```

Namely, when you put it in the request scope, then all properties would be reset to their defaults, which in your particular case apparently triggers a `disabled="true"`.

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked/2120183#2120183) (#5)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)

Comment: thanks.It's work.But I have a getList method for dataTable in the same managedBean.When I add new switched inputText (data) to db(so to datatable from this db),I update/request dataTable list.So if I use viewscoped,list of datatable is not up to date.So I should use RequestScoped or I create new managedBean for only this switch operation.What should I do?is this the only option (viewscoped)?Thanks again.

Comment: Then make sure in your action you also explicitly update the list in the viewscoped bean